# ObservableArray throwing undefined is not a function in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a problem where the following code crash on the line

```
self.DivisionRuleList.push(div);
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The list should be initialized, since I use the same list in another dropdown, that is rendering and I can see the values if I look it up in the console.

The returned object is adding to the array Divisions as it should.

My code:

```
Division = function() {
    this.id = ko.observable();
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.sex = ko.observable();
    this.businessTypeId = ko.observable();
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Division = ko.observable(new Division);
    self.Divisions = ko.observableArray();
    self.DivisionRuleList = ko.observableArray();

    self.submitDivision = function(element) {
        var json = ko.mapping.toJSON(self.Division);
        $.post("@Url.Action("AddDivision", "BusinessRules")", {
            json: json
        }).done(function (d) {

            var div = ko.mapping.fromJSON(d);
            self.Divisions.push(div);
            self.DivisionRuleList.push(div);

            self.Division(new Division());   
         })
         .fail(function (d) {
              alert("FAILED");         
         });
    };
}
```

content retruned in div (the json)

```
{  
    "Id":1042,
    "Sex":0,
    "SexString":"Herrar",
    "Name":"test",
    "BusinessTypeString":"Typ1",
    "DivisionFullname":"Typ1 Herrar test",
    "UserId":2,
    "Username":"Testanvändare",
    "Timestamp":"2014-07-24T13:40:19.733328+02:00",
    "TimestampString":"2014-07-24 13:40",
    "BusinessTypeId":1,
    "BusinessType":null
}
```

**update**

I use the DivisonRuleList in the following option list in the same view:'

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: ViewModel.DivisionRuleList(),
    optionsValue: 'Id',
    optionsText: function (item) {
        return item.BusinessType.Name() + ' ' + item.SexString() + ' ' + item.Name();
   },
   value: ViewModel.BusinessRule().divisionId">
</select>
```

If I remove this, it works fine. A clue perhaps?

ViewModel initialization

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var req = $.ajax("@Url.Action("GetDivisionsNoRule", "BusinessRules")", { cache: false });                
    ViewModel = new ViewModel();

    req.done(function(data) {
         ViewModel.DivisionRuleList = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
         ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);            
    });
});
```

Comment: where is the definition of `self.Division`?

Comment: Maybe it's not defined lol

Comment: Edited. Just removed a bit to much code creating the question.

Comment: well it quite obvious error is at `ko.mapping.fromJSON(d)` . can you post a sample of data you getting at `var div =`.

Comment: updated. You think? The var div is added normally to the Divisions list, and is added to my table where I use the list.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on your suspect line, what is the value of `self.DivisionRuleList`? Is it defined? Is there anywhere else in your code that could be setting it to `null` or `delete`ing it?

Comment: Everything is initialized as I can see. Though, I found something that could be a clue, see my updated answer.

Comment: Did you check console for errors?

Comment: @haim770 Yes, it throws the error I wrote in the description.

Comment: Can you add the part where you call `applyBindings()`?

Comment: @haim770 done. Still curious why it works when I remove the select/option list though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is BusinessType.Name defined? Guessing BusinessType was null, which got wrapped in a ko.observable, which has an undefined Name property.

Comment: @user373455 I've been shying away from writing more code which uses Knockout because of exactly this type of bug, just seems too easy to make. Instead I've been using ReactJS, which pulls off the neat trick of using the same code to do the initial render and for subsequent updates, while still having good performance. Means that there are no observable properties any more, so this sort of bug just doesn't happen.

Comment: Ye, it's pretty annoying. I think knockout is a bit tricky sometimes and I often run into these kind of problems. I will check ReactJS up, thank you!